# issue with c8ydevicecontrol.create

Tags: cumulocity

the code:

```
this.sendOperations = function () {
          var operation = {
              deviceId: '12161',
              com_cumulocity_model_WebCamDevice: {
                  name: 'take picture',
                  parameters: {
                      duration: '5s',
                      quality: 'HD'
                  }
              }
          };
          c8yDeviceControl.create(operation);
```

Result:
a new operation will be created in cumulocity server, but in the meantime, the chrome brower on which the app is runing will report some errors, although it looks like the app is still runing after that:

```
angular.js:9997 TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null
at k (deviceControl.js:267)
at wrappedCallback (angular.js:11498)
at wrappedCallback (angular.js:11498)
at angular.js:11584
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:12608)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:12420)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:12712)
at done (angular.js:8315)
at completeRequest (angular.js:8527)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:8466)
```

any suggestion? Thanks

D. Chen

Comment: Can you check if the response headers have a location?